# How can I join two collections with $in operator in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to join two collections with $in operator. Here is the collection example

[image]

How can I get output like following:

```
{
   "_id":10000,
   "items": [
              {
                  "_id":12345,
                  "productName": "laptop",
                  "unitPrice": 1000
              },
              {
                  "_id":54321,
                  "productName": "mouse",
                  "unitPrice": 20
              }

            ]
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) on an array and you can specify `as` to be `items` which will overwrite existing array.

According to the docs:

> If your localField is an array, you may want to add an $unwind stage to your pipeline. Otherwise, the equality condition between the localField and foreignField is foreignField: { $in: [ localField.elem1, localField.elem2, ... ] }

And that's what you need here

Try:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "items",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "items"
        }
    }
])
```